# Weird RecurrenceTable bug

Tags: bugs, difference-equations

**Bug introduced in 10.0 or earlier and persisting through 12.2 or later**

The output of `RecurrenceTable` seems to lose a level when there are more than 250 points and one variable.  Easiest to explain with an example:

*Good:*

```
RecurrenceTable[{n[t + 1] == 2 (1 - n[t]) n[t], n[0] == 0.1}, {n}, {t, 0, 249}]

(* {{0.1}, {0.18}, {0.2952}, {0.416114}, {0.485926}, {0.499604}, {0.5}, {0.5}, ... {0.5}} *)
```

*Bad:*

```
RecurrenceTable[{n[t + 1] == 2 (1 - n[t]) n[t], n[0] == 0.1}, {n}, {t, 0, 250}]

(* {{0.1}, 0.18, 0.2952, 0.416114, 0.485926, 0.499604, 0.5, 0.5, ... 0.5} *)
```

Having more than one variable works as expected:

```
RecurrenceTable[{n[t + 1] == 2 (1 - n[t]) n[t], m[t + 1] == 2 (1 - m[t]) m[t], n[0] == 0.1, m[0] == 0.1}, {n, m}, {t, 0, 250}]

(* {{0.1, 0.1}, {0.18, 0.18}, {0.2952, 0.2952}, {0.416114, 0.416114}, {0.485926, 0.485926}, {0.499604, 0.499604}, {0.5, 0.5}, {0.5, 0.5}, ... {0.5, 0.5}} *)
```

I've found a couple easy workarounds for this minimal example (e.g. use `n` instead of `{n}`, use `NestList` instead of `RecurrenceTable`), but I've got `RecurrenceTable` embedded in a general function that requires both a list of dependent variables and doesn't play well with `NestList`.  I just wanted to see if others have this same issue, which I'll report to WRI.  I'm using Mathematica 11.0.1 on MacOS 10.12.

Comment: It's a bug. For a workaround, try `Method -> {Compiled -> False}`.

Comment: @ilian Brilliant, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@ilian's fix in comments above works fine: add `Method -> {Compiled -> False}`.  I've also reported to WRI.

*Edit:*
But you know what, compiling is kind of a nice feature, so another workaround is to post-process the results, like

```
Replace[
  RecurrenceTable[{n[t + 1] == 2 (1 - n[t]) n[t], n[0] == 0.1}, {n}, {t, 0, 250}],
  n_?NumericQ -> {n}, 1]
```