# Can't make more than 249 Internal`Bags in a Table

Tags: list-manipulation, undocumented

I need a lot of [`` Internal`Bag ``s](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/845/internalbag-inside-compile) so I made them with `Table`.  It works fine for 249 or fewer `Bags` but goes horribly wrong for 250 or more:

```
Table[Internal`Bag[0], {i, 249}]
(* {Internal`Bag["<" 1 ">"], ... } *)

Table[Internal`Bag[0], {i, 250}]
(* {0, 1, 2, ..., 249} *)
```

What's causing this weird behavior and how can I avoid it?

Comment: This might possibly be fixed in the development version.

Comment: The issue seems fixed in v12.1 on Linux.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Seems to be the same underlying issue as [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/158186/): by default, `Table` compiles its argument when the number of values is 250 or more.  Evidently `` Internal`Bag `` doesn't like this!

If all `` Internal`Bag ``s are the same, then

```
ConstantArray[Internal`Bag[0], 250]
```

seems to work.

Otherwise, temporarily changing the `TableCompileLength` system option works:

```
tcl = SystemOptions["CompileOptions" -> "TableCompileLength"];
SetSystemOptions[
  "CompileOptions" -> {"TableCompileLength" -> \[Infinity]}];
Table[Internal`Bag[0], {i, 250}]
SetSystemOptions[tcl];
```

Perhaps, a general heuristic: if anything starts breaking or slowing down at 250, suspect behind-the-scenes Compilation.  See [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/69892), [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/55243/), [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/161060), and [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/128371) for more examples.

Comment: The default return value for ``Internal`Bag`` from `Compile` is the bag ID or something That would be my assumption for what's breaking. Better than the return value from ``NIntegrate`Heap`` (which it can't return even though it *can* use in compiled code).

Comment: As you are temporarily(!) modifying system settings, I would recommend wrapping your business in ``Internal`WithLocalSettings[]``, as was done [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/136017).